# Who was the architect of Knutstorp Castle?

Tags: architecture, 14th-century

Who was the architect of [Knutstorp Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knutstorp_Castle) in Sweden, [Tycho Brahe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tycho_Brahe)'s birthplace?

---

As we learned from helpful comments approaching the topic:

This estate was existing earlier but re-built under Tycho's father Otto in 1551: this country-seat (called Knudstrup Borg when Scania was still part of Denmark) dates to the middle of the 14th century and was acquired by Brahe's ancestors around 1500. The main building in existence in Tycho's time had been constructed by Otto Brahe in 1551, per a plaque on the building:

> "Anno Dom. 1551 lod leg Otthe Brade bijgge thette hus her star oc blef folkommne samme aar met mine kerre hustrue Beate Bilde Her Claus Bildes datter paa Liinngaardt"

Knudstrup / Knutstorp Castle came into the possession of the Brahe family when Tyge Axelsen Brahe (father of Otto Brahe) married the daughter Magdalena of the previous owner, the knight Oluf Stigsen Krognos. Sources differ whether the marriage occurred in 1502 or 1503.

If there were more architects than one in 1551, or if it was rebuilt by a different architect, I would like to know names of all of them.

EDIT: [The Swedish Wikipedia](https://sv.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knutstorps_borg) contains more info compared to the English one.

Comment: Please include the info that this estate was existing earlier but re-built under Tycho's father Otto in 1551, _if that's_ what you want to know.

Comment: From what I gather, this country-seat (called Knudstrup Borg when Scania was still part of Denmark) dates to the middle of the 14th century and was acquired by Brahe's ancestors around 1500. As LangLangC states, the main building in existence in Tycho's time had been constructed by Otto Brahe in 1551, per a plaque on the building: "Anno Dom. 1551 lod leg Otthe Brade bijgge thette hus her star oc blef folkommne samme aar met mine kerre hustrue Beate Bilde Her Claus Bildes datter paa Liinngaardt"

Comment: Knudstrup / Knutstorp Castle came into the possession of the Brahe family when Tyge Axelsen Brahe (father of Otto Brahe) married the daughter  Magdalena of the previous owner, the knight Oluf Stigsen Krognos. Sources differ whether the marriage occurred in 1502 or 1503.

Comment: @njuffa if you like to [edit] in your sources, we might clean up the comments?